# Unable to install printing package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, widget

> ```
> error: package net.nfet.flutter.printing does not exist flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new net.nfet.flutter.printing.PrintingPlugin());
> ```

build.gradle file-

```
android {
namespace ******
compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId ******
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Hello everyone, I was trying to install [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package in flutter but failed to so. I am getting errors. I don't know what is happening as I read documentation to install the package but it is still persisting. I tried every solution available online but could not resolve it.